# Why to cast a class to be compared before overriding equals()?

Tags: casting, equality

So in the code segment below, why do we cast the "other" class explicitly even after it has passed the equality test of getClass() results.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
.
.
.
if (getClass() != other.getClass()) return false;

Person person = (Person)other;
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: So you can access the members of that class.

Comment: the compiler will complain if you treat an `Object` as a `Person` without an explicit cast.  For instance, you'll fail if you use `other.firstName` but would be fine with `person.firstName` assuming the Person class has that member.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do `person.getterOnPerson()` when doing your comparison. Recall that the Object class does not contain all the necessary methods to retrieve the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

The casting is necessary for the code to be able to access any methods or fields in the `Person` object.

```
public boolean equals(Object other){

   if( !(other instanceof Person)){
       return false;
   }

   Person otherPerson = (Person)other;

   //now we can check equality
   return getLastname().equals(otherPerson.getLastname() )
        && getFirstname().equals(otherPerson.getFirstname() );
}
```

**EDIT**
If you want to check equality where objects are not direct subclasses you can also use `instanceof` to test if an object implements and interface.  For example the `List` interface is the parent object of `ArrayList`, `Vector` and `LinkedList`.  If you wanted to test equality of 2 objects where their types were any of those, you can by checking that the both objects implement `List` and that their elements are all equal and in the same order.

Here is the code from `AbstractList` which does just that.  Notice that we have to cast to a list to be able to call the method `listIterator()` on the other object:

```
 public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;

    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator<?> e2 = ((List<?>) o).listIterator();
    while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }
    //this check will return false if either iterator
    //still has elements left which means the lists aren't the same size. 
    return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Does it mean that we cannot compare objects of two classes which are from two different trees? I mean if one class is not the subclass of the other...